# Can a ppa repository belong to Main?

Tags: ppa, repository

Software repositories in Ubuntu are divided into four categories or components - main, restricted, universe and multiverse,
according to 
support offered by Ubuntu
and
free and open source: how well it meets the goals of Ubuntu's free software philosophy.

In my source file, I saw that all the ppa's belong to main, e.g.:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kalakris/okular/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kalakris/okular/ubuntu precise main
```

While both being free and open source, Main is officially supported by the Ubuntu security and distribution team. 
and
Universe  is community maintained, but not officially supported.

Shouldn't a ppa belong to Universe instead of Main?

Answer (score 2):

PPAs do not belong to the main Ubuntu archive, no. However, PPAs only have a *main* archive, as they are not part of the Ubuntu archive itself. They do not have *universe* or *multiverse*. Nothing in a PPA is supported by officially supported Ubuntu, generally speaking.

However, the Launchpad Terms of Service also prohibit you from uploading any proprietary binary software to a PPA. You can only upload debian source packages to a PPA. And you can only have private PPAs or PPAs with proprietary software, if you are paying for a Commercial subscription that enables you to host proprietary projects on Launchpad.

Comment: What does "main" mean for PPAs?

Comment: It doesn't _mean_ anything special.